# Is there a term for trying to remember a word, but only remembering its first letter?

Tags: memory, terminology, language

This happens to me frequently. I'll say, "Oh you know that guy... uhh... I can't remember his name. But he starts with a 'Z'." You can remember part of the word but not the whole word.

Is there a term for this situation? What causes it?

Comment: **Brainfart**. Although it's informal, I did hear someone using it in your case.

Comment: Anomic aphasia, also known as dysnomia, nominal aphasia, and amnesic aphasia; is a severe problem with recalling words or names. Wikipedia is a good source of info on the subject. Severe cases sometimes are traced back to a blow and subsequent damage to the left side of the brain.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is called the [Tip of the Tongue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_of_the_tongue) phenomenon.

> People in a tip-of-the-tongue state can often recall one or more features of the target word, such as the first letter, its syllabic stress, and words similar in sound and/or meaning. Individuals report a feeling of being seized by the state, feeling something like mild anguish while searching for the word, and a sense of relief when the word is found.

It's a very common phenomenon, and it presents itself in several similar forms, as the Wikipedia description notes. Remembering just the first letter is a common form but not the only cue.

There are a couple of suggested causes, but generally the problem is failure to *completely* retrieve information you "know" is in fact there. The Wikipedia article has some information on the general theories.

Comment: Great answer. This is the foundational paper for the topic in the cognitive psychology literature: Brown, R. & McNeill, D. (1966). The "tip of the tongue" phenomenon. Journal of Verbal Learning and Verbal Behavior, 5, 325-337.