# What was her/his name again.....ahh got it!

Tags: memory, measurement

You all know the situation described in the title. You forgot something and start to search your memory and then after quite a while it jumps right in front of you, out of nowhere.

My questions are:

1. What happens in the brain during that moment of awareness?
2. Is it different from when we know something right away, since the subconscious mind is working for quite a while to produce the answer?
3. Is it possible to measure this moment and was it done already?

Comment: This Question is similar to http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/1/421 .

Comment: Not sure all 3 questions should be asked in one question...I think some are a lot deeper than you might realize.

Comment: This is also almost the same as [this question](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/676/29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to look up literature on the "Tip of the Tongue" (TOT) phenomenon.  It's been studied since the 60s I believe and can be experimentally reproduced.

Comment: [Another cogsci.SE answer](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/677/421) goes into some detail on this phenomenon.